# Checking if number of characters in file is divisible by 3

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I'm trying to check if the number of nucleotide base characters in my dna file is a multiple of 3 and I have the following code that keeps giving me error:

```
var4=$(wc -c < $1 | bc)
var5=$($var4 % 3)

if [ "$var5" -eq 0 ]; then
```

As you can see the code above is not complete but I'm just showing the part where I'm having a problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014569/11972400

Comment: "_that keeps giving me error"_. What error?

Comment: @roaima Probably a command not found error in the assignment to `var5`.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes almost certainly. But if people want free help it's not too much to ask for proper fault descriptions

Comment: @roaima I'm totally agreeing with you.

Comment: @RajveerSingh have you put your code through https://shellcheck.net/ yet? If not, I'd really recommend you use that to identify the first set of errors.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your nucleotides are encoded using the letters in the group `acgtn`, the following command will delete everything that is not a character from that group (e.g. newlines and spaces etc.) and then count the remaining characters:

```
ncount=$( tr -d -c 'acgtn' <"$1" | wc -c )
```

You may then check this number with a simple test, but note use of `$((...))` rather than `$(...)`:

```
if [ "$(( ncount % 3 ))" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'nucleotide count is multiple of 3'
fi
```

If you use upper-case letters, or a mix of the two, then extend the string used with `tr` appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all non-newline characters in groups of three, we can do:

```
sed 's/...//g' file
```

If the result is only empty lines, all lines had multiple of three characters.

If the input is not one line and may contain other characters (including newlines), then, remove anything that is not nucleotide base characters (assuming uppercase `ACGTN`), including the newlines:

```
{ <file tr -cd 'ACGTN'; echo; } | sed 's/...//g'
```

If the result of that is empty (only a newline), the count of base characters is multiple of 3.

Assuming you want to stop the script (exit) if the count is not multiple of 3, use this:

```
if [ "$( { <file tr -cd 'ACGTN'; echo; } | sed 's/...//g')" ]; then
    echo 'nucleotide count is not multiple of 3'
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` option

```
f=$(sed -E "s/[actgn]{3}//g" file); echo ${#f}
```

Just delete all contiguous valid groups of 3 bases and if you have anything other than a zero length string left at the end then you have a problem....although this will allow new lines provided the break is at a multiple of 3 bases.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`, *GNU* `grep` and `wc`, but no variables:

```
(exit $(( $(grep -io '[acgtn]' file | wc -l)%3 )) )
```

...which returns a *true* exit code only if the dna chars are in multiples of three.

Using this in code might look like:

```
if (exit $(( $(grep -io '[acgtn]' file | wc -l)%3 )) ); then
```